# VIrtual hosts for wild card domain not working

Tags: apache-2.2, nginx, virtualhost

I have configured apache to run alongside with nginx on port 8080.

For some odd reason, I also have a wildcard domain defined at my DNS server, I've checked it, and it works(zazazazzaaaz.mysite.com still points to correct IP).

For some odd reason when I am trying to create virtual hosts for sites such as blog.mysite.com or app.mysite.com, it won't work.

Example VirtualHost  code from sites-available dir:

```
<virtualhost *:8080>

  # Admin email, Server Name (domain name) and any aliases
  ServerAdmin support@mysite.com
  ServerName  blog1.mysite.com:8080
  ServerAlias blog1.mysite.com:8080

  # Index file and Document Root (where the public files are located)
  DocumentRoot /var/www/vhosts/blog.mysite.com/htdocs/wordpress/
  DirectoryIndex index.php


  # Custom log file locations
  LogLevel warn
  ErrorLog  /var/www/vhosts/blog.mysite.com/log/error.log
  CustomLog /var/www/vhosts/blog.mysite.com/log/access.log combined

</virtualhost>
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Exactly what doesn't work?

Comment: Apache is not serving the pages at  /var/www/vhosts/blog.mysite.com/htdocs/wordpress/

Answer (score 1):

A specific error would be helpful. E.g. a description of the page displayed in your browser. Perhaps you are getting a 404, a forbidden message, the default browser "timeout" message.

Here's a few pointers:

1. You have specified port 8080 on the servername directive as well as on the Virtualhost directive. While this might not be the source of your problem, it seems pointless. I would remove it.
2. You have a serverAlias the same as the server name. Again, this seems pointless.
3. Check that you have adjusted your Listen directive in httpd.conf/apache2.conf so apache is listening on port 8080
4. If there is a firewall between your webserver and the "outside world" you will need to configure that accordingly.
5. Check /var/www/vhosts/blog.mysite.com/log/error.log for any indication of the problem.